# "All scalars are invariant": meaning in the context of changing basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, change-of-basis

I'm interested in understanding a comment by [Chapter 0](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/tensorbook/ch0.pdf) of McCullaugh (1987). To keep the question self-contained, I'll provide some context below. Thank you.

---

Suppose I have vector space $V$ with $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Let $v\in V$ be represented by $\sum_{i=1}^nv_ie_i$ where $v_i$'s are scalars. Let $K$ be some invertible $n\times n$ matrix and define new basis vectors
$$
\bar{e}_i=\sum_{j=1}^nK_{ij} e_j\iff (e_1\;\cdots\;e_n)K'=(\bar{e}_1\;\cdots\;\bar{e}_n).
$$
Then $v$ can also be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{v}_i\bar{e}_i$ where
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{v}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \bar{v}_n
\end{pmatrix}=(K')^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
**Comment of interest** (first paragraph, page 14):

> ...(that) basis vectors are arbitrary up to linear transformation effectively means that all calculations are independent of the choice of the basis. In particular, all scalars are **invariant** i.e. independent of the choice of basis.

**Question**: what does **invariant** mean here? The new coordinates $\bar{v}_1,\ldots,\bar{v}_n$ above are not the same as the original coordinates $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ which are scalars.

Comment: I assume it's simply supposed to mean that a scalar matrix is unchanged by a change of basis. The $v_i$ do not come from a scalar matrix, so they are not invariant.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Are you saying that if $v_i$'s are all the same, then they stay unchanged?

Comment: among other things, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment as it is in your post is taken out of context: in your post, it seems to be a part of some considerations about vectors - in which case one naturally asks how could scalars be particular cases of vectors (exactly your question). In reality, this comment in its original context is a part of some considerations about **tensors**, and in this case things are clear, because a scalar means a tensor of type $(0,0)$ or, if you prefer, an element of $V^0 \otimes (V^*)^0$, which is after all isomorphic to the base field.

To clarify this with an example, consider $\Bbb R^2$ with the basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ and the scalar $3 \in \Bbb R$. Now perform some arbitrary change of basis in $\Bbb R^2$ - it doesn't matter which one. Does $3$ change in any way? No, it doesn't even feel this change of basis - and this is the simplest type of invariance under a change of coordinates: being constant. (The reason why scalars -i.e. numbers- are invariant under such changes of basis being that they do not, in fact, have coordinates. Think for yourself: what are the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the number $3$?)

Comment: +1 You're right that I left out some context. My understanding of the tensor approach is that it allows one to frame calculations in a vector space as calulations in the base field. What trips me up is the phrase "In particular", which suggests some logical implication in the exposition of which I don't see any. If you can clarify some more, I'll really appreciate it. If not, I think your answer is a good enough starting point so that once I read enough of McCullaugh, this concern will eventually make sense to me.

Comment: @yurnero: I'd say that your starting point (*"the tensor approach [...] allows one to frame calculations in a vector space as calulations in the base field"*) is mistaken, no wonder that it leads you astray. One possible understanding of a tensor of type $(m,n)$ is as a mapping $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ such that $T(u_1, \dots, u_i + v_i, \dots, u_n) = T(u_1, \dots, u_i, \dots, u_n) + T(u_1, \dots, v_i, \dots, u_n) \ \forall i$ and $T(u_1, \dots, \alpha u_i, \dots, u_n) = \alpha T(u_1, \dots, u_i, \dots, u_n) \ \forall i$... (continued)

Comment: @yurnero: (continued) ...The other approach understands tensors of type $(m,n)$ as the elements of a certain quotient space of $V^m \times (V^*)^n$ - but since I don't know whether you feel comfortable with quotient spaces I won't mention it. In any case, both approaches are "isomorphic", the former one being more concrete and easier to grasp for a beginner. Don't worry, tensors are a stumbling block for many students, and I believe that this is the main reason why many tend to avoid abstract differential geometry (where tensors are ubiquitous).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, writing "all calculations" is misleading. What one can say is the following: Given two vectors $x$, $y\in V$ the sum $z:=x+y$ is a well defined element of $V$ which does not depend on the chosen basis. In the same vein: You obtain the the coordinates of $z$ by adding the coordinates of $x$ and of $y$, whatever the chosen basis is. Similarly, the vector $w:=\alpha x$ is a well defined element of $V$ which does not depend on the chosen basis. Furthermore you obtain the the coordinates of $w$ by multiplying the coordinates of $x$ **with this very** $\alpha$, whatever the chosen basis is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to clarify that I didn't downvote. I'm still comprehending Alex M.'s answer.